# Построчный ввод в массив с клавиатуры

Tags: c#, массивы

Скажите, каким образом в массив можно ввести несколько значений с клавиатуры?
Например, есть задача вводить ввести в матрицу 3 на 3 значения, как ввести сразу три цифры через пробел, чтобы это правильно считывалось?
Вот как у меня это выглядит сейчас, когда ввод значения идёт с новой строки:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("mas[" + i + "," + j + "]: ");
        mas[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ввести все значения в одну строку:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

int[,] array = new int[x, y];
Console.Write("Enter the matrix in one line: ")
int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        array[i, j] = numbers[i * y + j];
```

Можно вводить значения по строкам:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

int[,] array = new int[x, y];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the line (i = {0}): ", i);
    int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        array[i, j] = numbers[j];
}
```

По поводу использованных конструкций:

- `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();`
  считывает из консоли строку, разделяет её по пробелам, для каждой
  подстроки вызывает `int.Parse` и приводит полученную коллекцию к типу
  массива.
- `Console.Write("Enter the line (i = {0}): ", i);` форматирует строку,
  подставляя в позиции `{0}`, `{1}` и т.д. аргументы, следующие за строкой
  формата.

Comment: И да, я знаю, что Select(s => int.Parse(s)) можно заменить на Select(int.Parse), но я считаю первый вариант более наглядным.